# Split person[0].email into ['person', '0', 'email']

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know if this has been asked before, because English is not my first language and I don't know the keywords to search.

So basically I have the following input element,

```
<input type="email" name="person[0].email" />
```

I would like to split the name into 3 parts like `["person", "0", "email"]`.

I have tried using `/(\[[^[\]]])|\./` but it gives `["person", "[0]", "", undefined, "email"]`.
Also, for `a[0][1].b[3].c`, it should output `["a", "0", "1", "b", "3", "c"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.match` instead of `.split`

```js
console.log("person[0].email".match(/\w+/g));
```

**Note** (*thanks* `@npinti`): in case if in name will be `_` my first example will match also `_`, so in this case you need just use regexp like this

```js
    console.log("person[0].email".match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (note the extra underscrore). I am not sure if the OP would like to keep the underscore as part of the match.

Comment: @npinti yes, good point. However in answer there is not mention about `_` only `person[0].email`, anyway I vote up on you comment, it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to break on anything which is not a letter or a number, thus you could use this: `[^A-Za-z0-9]+`. An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/sZ0nO3/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this split:

```
var m = person[0].email".split(/[.\[\]]+/g)
//=> ["person", "0", "email"]
```

OR:

```
m = "a[0][1].b[3].c".split(/[.\[\]]+/g)
//=> ["a", "0", "1", "b", "3", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the following format: `name[i].prop`, you can do this without regular expressions:

```js
function splitName(s)
{
  var parts1 = s.split('].');
  var parts2 = parts1[0].split('[');

  return [parts2[0], parts2[1], parts1[1]];
}

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(splitName('name[i].prop')) + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(splitName('person[0].email')) + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(splitName('a[0].b')) + '<br/>';
```

It is less elegant, not universal and works only for the specified format. However, there are no regular expressions and if you work only with this format - then why not? :)